# Using `rsync` and `ssh` in perl causes unexplained timeout?

Tags: linux, perl, ssh, rsync

I'm running a two-stage process on a large number of files.

CODE:

```
$server_sleep = 1;
$ssh_check = 'ssh '.$destination_user."@".$destination_hostname.' "test -e '.$destination_path.$file_filename.'.txt && echo 1 || echo 0"';
while (`$ssh_check` ne "1\n") { # for some reason, the backticks return the 1 with a newline
   $upload_command = "/usr/bin/rsync -qogt --timeout=".$server_sleep." --partial --partial-dir=".$destination_path."partials ".$file_path."/".$file_filename.".txt ". $destination_user."@".$destination_hostname.":".$destination_path;

   sleep $server_sleep; # to avoid hammering the server (for the rsync)
   $upload_result = `$upload_command  2>&1`;
   $file_errorReturn = "FAIL" if $?;
   if (defined($file_errorReturn)) {
      #log an error. there is code to do this, but I have omitted it.
   }
   sleep $server_sleep; # to avoid hammering the server (for the ssh check)
   $server_sleep++; # increase the timeout if failures continue
}
```

BEHAVIOUR:
For the first few files this works fine (which should take care of your first few questions about keys, access, permissions, typos, etc.), and at some point, I get this error back:

```
ssh: connect to host remote_server.com port 22: Connection timed out
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(600) [sender=3.0.6]
```

I get this regardless of if I have specified -e ssh in the command, so I assume there is a default somewhere to ssh (which is fine). I have also tried the rsync section with scp, and it resulted in a similar connection timed out error:

```
ssh: connect to host remote_server.com port 22: Connection timed out
lost connection
```

QUESTIONS YOU MAY HAVE

1) Because the first few files work, the path is clear for this to work (ie there should be no problems with typos, permissions, etc.), and my debug code outputs the actual command that is tried, and this works fine in the command line (even on the files that fail in the script).

2) I have tried to add -vvvvv to both ssh and rsync, but I don't know how to get it to output more error information WITHIN my script. All I ever get is the above errors and when I run it on the command line, I get no errors. (even after I added "2>&1" and ">> log.txt" to the end both commands.) It is certainly possible that I'm not collecting all the logs I should be, so your help there would be appreciated as well.

3) I am just a regular user on both the local and remote machines.

```
local: rsync  version 3.0.6  protocol version 30
remote: rsync  version 3.0.9  protocol version 30
path to ssh and rsync is the same on both.
```

4) In response to the excellent question (from qwrrty) in the comment (thanks!):
It is not terribly consistent. The files are numbered and they were being run in the following order: 4, 5, 3, 2, 1. It WAS failing on 1. Then I removed 3. It still failed on 1. When I put 3 back in, it started to fail on 2.

The files are all small (5mb max), so the transfer is basically instant (as the machines are not far from each  other physically or networky).
Please let me know if you need more detail. Thanks in advance for any advice you can offer.

Comment: Do the errors happen with any consistency? e.g. do they always happen when transferring a particular file, or after the same number of files have been transferred?  Is there any correlation between file size and the timeouts?

Comment: More generally, your code is running two ssh/rsync sessions for each file transferred: one to see if you've started duplicating files, and one to transfer the actual file. Would it make sense instead just to run rsync with the `--ignore-existing` option to prevent uploading any files that exist on the receiver, and then just run it a single time with a list of all the candidate files?

Comment: Great questions! 1) it happened on one file, so I removed one in the list, it continued to error on that one file, so I added the removed file back in. Then it happened one file earlier. If that makes any sense.

Comment: 2) No correlation between filesize and timeout. The biggest file is 5mb and the to machines are not far from each other (both physically and networky), and it has happened on the smaller files too (a few hundred k)

Comment: 3) Your suggestion with --ignore-existing makes sense, and this is actually the method I used in the first place. I added the second check to create the loop to continue trying (as I assumed that it was just a magic combination of pauses that would fix it).

Comment: Well, I've posted the way I'd try to resolve this problem in an answer. It's not exactly an answer to your question about why ssh is timing out, but it may help resolve the bigger problem anyway. Or maybe not.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to minimize extra ssh sessions and subprocesses by doing it all in a single rsync? Something like this?

```
open (RSYNC, "| /usr/bin/rsync -qogt \
                  --files-from=- \
                  --ignore-existing \
                  --timeout=${server_sleep} \
                  --partial --partial_dir=${destination_path}partials \
                  ${destination_user}@${destination_hostname}:${destination_path}");
for $f (@big_list_of_files) {
    print RSYNC $f, "\n";
}
close RSYNC;
```

rsync has quite a lot of smarts built into it around how to transfer and synchronize large numbers of files at a time, and in my experience it usually works best to let it do as much of the work as possible.

Comment: Great suggestion! I tried something similar, but it still got caught up in checking if the file had actually made the trip. I like your way of doing it though, and my way was definitely different, so I will try to express what you've got in my code.

Comment: Ok, so I have it integrated (I think), and I'm now getting an rsync error. Is there a way I can debug it to see what rsync command was actually done? I made one change to your code. I added a \ before the @ because perl thought I was making an array. Otherwise, I just copied and pasted.

Comment: Sure, you could do something like `$rsync_cmd = "/usr/bin/rsync -qogt --files-from=- ..."; print "running $rsync_cmd\n"; open (RSYNC, "| $rsync_cmd")`

Comment: ok, the command is `/usr/bin/rsync -qogt --files-from=- --ignore-existing --partial --partial-dir=/var/sites/site/upload/partials user@server.com:/var/sites/site/upload/`. And the error I get is `rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at options.c(1652) [client=3.0.6]` which appears to be a problem with --files-from=-. I am totally unfamiliar with this option, and the man page says that what I have should work...Sorry to keep pestering. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: If you copy that command on the command line (and pipe a list of files into it) do you get the same error?  If so, I guess it's time to go groveling through the rsync man page for a bit :-/

Comment: Yup. That's the command line error as well. Ok, back to the man page. Thanks! It's late where I am, so I'll probably get after it tomorrow.